# Bootstrap popover on click event not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

My popover isn't working when I trigger an evenLimitClick event in my fullcalendar. It works fine in my dayClick event, but nothing happens in my eventLimitClick. Here is my [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4v65ggos/22/)
I even tried setting the popover to be called on the parent (ex. $(this).parent().popover, but that didn't work either.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    var eventsArray = [{
        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date()
    }, {
        title: 'Test2',
        start: new Date("2015-04-21")
    }, {
        title: 'Test3',
        start: new Date("2015-04-21")
    }];

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next', //today',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        selectable: true,
        events: eventsArray,
        eventLimit: 1,

        eventLimitClick: function (cellInfo, jsEvent) {
            $(this).popover({
                html: true,
                placement: 'bottom',
                container: 'body',
                title: function () {
                    return $("#events-popover-head").html();
                },
                content: function () {
                    return $("#events-popover-content").html();
                }
            });

            $(this).popover('show');
        },
        dayClick: function (cellInfo, jsEvent) {
            $(this).popover({
                html: true,
                placement: 'bottom',
                container: 'body',
                title: function () {
                    return $("#events-popover-head").html();
                },
                content: function () {
                    return $("#events-popover-content").html();
                }
            });

            $(this).popover('show');
        },
    })

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.js"></script>

<div style="border:solid 2px red;">
    <div id='calendar'></div>
    <div id="events-popover-head" class="hide">Events</div>
    <div id="events-popover-content" class="hide">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: arent you calling only the js files from jquery? where is your js for bootstrap?

Comment: hi. in my fiddle, you can see that I checked off the bootstrap version. The fiddle is loading bootstrap. The snippet here on SO isn't working, SO forced me to insert code for any question that has a fiddle link in it.

Comment: ohh i see sorry i didnt see the jsfiddle link

Comment: if you can help me out I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the eventLimitClick event change following:

```
$(this).popover
```

To

```
$(cellInfo.dayEl)
```

cellInfo.dayEl is the clicked Day cell element for which you want to show popover.

I have updated the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4v65ggos/24/) also